# how to get the coordinates out?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, xcode4.3, arcgis

I'm trying to extract the x and y coordinates out from `self.mapView.gps.currentPoint` how can I do it?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
NSLog(@"Location1 : %@", self.mapView.gps.currentPoint);
```

Results:

```
Location1 : AGSMutablePoint: x = 29841.008687, y = 40101.841687, spatial reference: 
    [AGSSpatialReference: wkid = 0, wkt = "PROJCS["SVY21",
    GEOGCS[
        "SVY21[WGS84]",
        DATUM[
            "D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]
        ],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",28001.642],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",38744.572],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.8333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",1.366666666666667],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]
]"]`
```

and if I use `NSLog(@"Location2 : %@", self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x);`
It will return me an error bad access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the format string in your `NSLog`

```
NSLog(@"Location2 : %@", self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x);
```

The `%@` means it's expecting an obj-c object. You're passing it a `CGFloat`. You should replace this with `%f` or maybe `%g` (those both take a floating-point value but output slightly differently).

```
NSLog(@"Location2 : %f", self.mapView.gps.currentPoint.x);
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"Location2 : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(self.mapView.gps.currentPoint));` By using that it return me an error: `passing 'AGSPoint *' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGPoint'(aka 'struct CGPoint');`

Comment: @user1495988: Yes sorry, I deleted that additional advice when I realized you have an `AGSMutablePoint` instead of a `CGPoint`. I was making a bad assumption as to what `currentPoint` returned.